# calculate the number of digits in a numeric vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numeric in R:

```
 c(0.9, 0.81)
```

and I'd like to extract the number of digits for each element in this vector. The command will return, in this case, `1` and `2` since the digits are `9` and `81`. Is there a convenient way to do it? Also, if the result is `1`, how can I expand to two digits? For example, I'd like a returned vector to be

```
 c(0.90, 0.81)
```

Comment: Try `format(v1, nsmall=2)` for printing or `sprintf('%.2f', v1)`  Do you want to return it as `numeric` class?  Perhaps `round(v1,2)`

Comment: Type `v` in the console and you will get `0.90` and `0.81`. The vector automatically prints all elements with the highest number of digits of any one number in the vector.

Comment: I need to create the same function (which counts the number of digits in a numric vector, suppose there's only one object in the vector), but I MUST do it using    ' while'    loop. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- c(0.9,0.81,32.52,0);
nchar(sub('^0+','',sub('\\.','',x)));
## [1] 1 2 4 0
```

This strips the decimal point, then strips all leading zeroes, and finally uses the string length as an indirect means of computing the number of significant digits. It naturally returns zero for a zero input, but you can use an `if` expression to explicitly test for that case and return one instead, if you prefer.

As akrun mentioned, for printing with two digits after the decimal:

```
sprintf('%.2f',x);
## [1] "0.90"  "0.81"  "32.52" "0.00"
```

Comment: This answer has a bug in it. It will strip away leading zeroes even when they are after the decimal point. So "0.0001" would give the answer 1, despite 4 being the correct one. Thought I'd point that out since this answer is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Phil The correct answer for 0.0001 is 1. Leading zeroes are not generally considered to be significant digits, even when they occur after the decimal point.

Answer (score 8):

To count the digits after the decimal, you can use `nchar`

```
sapply(v, nchar) - 2  # -2 for "." and leading 0
# 1 2
```

Comment: Or `nchar(sub('.*\\.', '', v1))`  BTW, `nchar(v1)-2` should also work

Comment: You may need to mention that this is not general.  For example `32.52`

Comment: @akrun yes, as akrun says