# Count the number of integer digits

Tags: r

I want to count the number of digits before the decimal point for a numeric vector x with numbers greater or equal to 1. For example, if the vector is

```
x <- c(2.85, 356.01, 66.1, 210.0, 1445.11, 13.000)
```

my code should return a vector containing integers 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2

Does any know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate the number of digits in a numeric vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894169/calculate-the-number-of-digits-in-a-numeric-vector-in-r) -- only need a slight variation on that: `nchar(sub('\\.[0-9]+', '', x))`

Comment: Not very versed in R, but one option is to `int(floor(x))`, to drop the trailing decimals in `x`, and then you could convert to a string and count the characters.

Comment: `nchar(as.integer(x))`

Comment: Yeah, very likely a dupe, but I'd do `ceiling(log10(x))`, which doesn't appear in duck's link. (See Gregor's comment for a correction.)

Comment: @Frank I think `floor(log10(x)) + 1`, so that 10 powers are counted correctly.

Comment: Language agnostic version of the q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655754/finding-the-number-of-digits-of-an-integer

Answer (score 35):

This is probably the best way (for positive numbers):

```
floor(log10(x)) + 1
```

If you want an answer that works for negative numbers too, add in an `abs()`:

```
floor(log10(abs(x))) + 1
```

The `log10` method will not work if the input is exactly 0, so if you want a robust solution with that method, handle 0 as a special case:

```
n_int_digits = function(x) {
  result = floor(log10(abs(x)))
  result[!is.finite(result)] = 0
  result
}
```

You can also use `nchar(trunc(x))`, but this seems to behave poorly for large numbers. It will also count leading 0s, whereas the `log` method will not.

Comment: OP's question was specifically about numbers greater than 1. Numbers less than 1 would need additional handling, something like `ifelse(x < 1, 0, ::code from the answer::)`... depending on how you want negative numbers handled.

Comment: `nchar(trunc(x))` fails for negative numbers. I know you were discussing the logarithm solution, but I figured I'd point that out too.

Comment: nchar(trunc(x)) fails for huge numbers. For example, ```n<-1.23e+20``` gives  ```nchar(trunc(n))``` as ```8```!

Answer (score 15):

## Character Counting

For small problems, I like the `nchar()` solution the best, with one modification for negative values:

```
nDigits <- function(x) nchar( trunc( abs(x) ) )

# Test
nDigits(100)
nDigits(-100)
# both have 3 digits

nDigits(3)
nDigits(-3)
nDigits(0.1)
nDigits(-0.1)
# all have 1 digit

nDigits(1 / .Machine$double.eps)
nDigits(-1 / .Machine$double.eps)
# both have 16 digits
```

## Base 10 Logarithm

If you want to make the logarithm solution work, then you need considerations for negative values and values between 0 and 1. To me, this solution is a tad more complicated:

```
nDigits2 <- function(x){

  truncX <- floor(abs(x))

  if(truncX != 0){
    floor(log10(truncX)) + 1
  } else {
    1
  }

}
```

## Speed Performance

Here is the output from the microbenchmark comparison (100,000 reps). The code for the character-counting solution is simpler, but slower (by a factor of 3-4):

For integers > 1 (Unit: nanoseconds):

```
          expr  min   lq      mean median   uq     max neval
  nDigits(100) 1711 2139 2569.2819   2566 2994 2234046 1e+05
 nDigits2(100)    0  428  861.5435    856  856 5670216 1e+05
```

For *really tiny* decimals (Unit: nanoseconds):

```
                           expr  min   lq     mean median   uq     max neval
 nDigits(1/.Machine$double.eps) 2994 4277 5066.321   4705 4705 4477928 1e+05
nDigits2(1/.Machine$double.eps)  428 1283 1588.382   1284 1711 2042458 1e+05
```