# Format numeric to two-digits

Tags: r, floating-point, formatting, decimal

I have a column of numeric class, e.g.: `v <- c(12345, 2345, 7689900)`.

I know that every number is actually of the form `12.345, 23.45, 76.89900`, ie every numeric has two digits and the rest is decimals.

How can I convert the vector to this format? No decimal should be cropped in the process.

Comment: What happens when the input is 1 digit or 2 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a numeric vector, one option could be:

```
v/10^(nchar(v) - 2)

[1] 12.345 23.450 76.899
```

---

**Edit:**

In cases when we have more than 20 digits, we can [Count the number of integer digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190862/680068) using *log10*:

```
v/10^(floor(log10(abs(v))) + 1 - 2)
```

Comment: Just to note: `nchar(1234567890123456789012345)` would give you 20 not 25.

Comment: @zx8754 thank you for your edit, very interesting :)

Comment: No problems! Since this is an accepted solution **and** I stole the idea from the linked post, I didn't want to post yet another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex we can capture the data in two groups separated by `"."`.

```
sub('(..)(.*)', '\\1.\\2', v)
#[1] "12.345"   "23.45"    "76.89900"
```

You can wrap this in `as.numeric` if you want to perform some manipulation on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.numeric(paste0(substring(v,1,2), ".", substring(v,3)))
# [1] 12.345 23.450 76.899
```